# Meaning of "fly down"

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

What does it mean when someone who is distant (maybe in another state) asks you to "fly down" (provided no additional context)?

Are they referring to how you would make it there (by plane) ou are the just urging you to hurry up and get there quickly?

Thanks!

Comment: The expression would usually be interpreted as **come by (passenger) plane**. There are alternative methods of flight (hot air balloons, paragliders etc) but they're a bit hit and miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Fly” usually means to travel on a passenger plane, but in very limited contexts (probably not this one) it can refer to driving so fast that it feels like flying—or that any bump in the road might cause your car to (briefly) become airborne.

In the context of travel, the words “down”, “up” or “over” can each substitute for either “here” or “there”, with the exact meaning being determined by context. These usually refer to compass direction, but you may see people occasionally use them for relative importance or other "logical" direction.

Comment: Thanks @StephenS. Could you clarify how your personal view of the trip would affect your picking one of "down", "up", "over" or even "out" (disregarding geographic factors)?

Comment: Yes. *I **flew** down the stairs* would mean that I ran quickly down the stairs. Or *the news **flew** down from head office* would mean that the news was quick to arrive. That's one of the other senses of *fly*.

Comment: @RicardoBaptista Generally speaking, *up*, *down*, and *over* do ***not*** disregard geographic factors, and that's what determines their use. For instance, if I'm flying south, I would never tell somebody that I was flying *up* to see them.